# QGIS inside buffer with attributes

Tags: qgis, buffer

Fairly similar to 
[Inside buffer with attributes in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402/arcgis-inside-buffer-with-attributes)
but in QGIS.

It would be convenient if the buffer layer inherited the attributes of the parent. Also I am doing inside buffers (-ve distance and dissolve).

If there is no such function, please let me know a workflow for joining the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you already wrote, an "inside" buffer can be created by specifying a negative buffer distance. And without dissolve, the resulting features contain the original attributes.