# How to visualize texture along borders of multipart polygon

Tags: qgis, cartography, symbology, borders

[image: texturedBoundary]

I came across this [map](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/07/recent-labelling-improvements-in-qgis-master/) and would like to replicate the textured styling found along the borders.  I'm starting with a multipart polygon but my process has perhaps too many steps. I'm using QGIS 2.8.2.

1. Processing algorithm: Convert original polygon to lines
2. Processing algorithm: Fixed distance buffer
3. Clip buffer using the original multipart polygon
4. Style the clipped buffer with Line Pattern Fill, adjusting transparency, line width, etc.

Here is my output:
[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this effect in fewer steps?  I sense I'm overlooking an option like color burst, but where you can use a line pattern as a fill.  Or, perhaps there's a way to do an inverted or negative buffer, which would save me the clipping step.

**Update:**
Buffers with negative values create smaller versions of the original multipart polygons, not a sort of boundary area.  (Note: I'm using Vector/Geoprocessing/Create Buffer.)

I think the buffer layer itself does need to be clipped too, presuming you have outermost boundaries to consider.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a future version will be able to do this in less steps - the blog post is based on new features coming to QGIS 2.12

Comment: This [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94326/black-white-hatching-pattern-fills-in-qgis) shows how to do hatching with polygons and this [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/qgis-inside-buffer-with-attributes) talks about using a negative value for the buffers. I am not really familur with QGIS, but these 2 links make it sound achievable.

Comment: I think polygon - boundary - buffer is right but you don't need to clip your existing then, draw the buffer with a stroke fill over the top of the exiting polygons with a transparent background as the stroke is the same for each. In your sample map the strokes fade, that would be more difficult to emulate but I think not totally impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from what you wrote and the links in the comments sections, I got a more refined hatched boundary (only within the polygons).

[image]

I used the "Difference Tool" (Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Difference) and used the following settings to clip the buffer to the extent that I wanted:

[image]

I used a -20m value for the buffer, but if you wanted longer hatched lines you could use a greater value.

Hope this helps. Oh This was done on QGIS 2.2.0