# Alternative quicker workflows to the standard Buffer tool in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, buffer, performance

I have a point layer representing oil and gas exploration wells containing 500,000 features and have created a 50km dissolved buffer polygon to use in another workflow:
[image]

The completion time for the buffer was 16 hours, of which is unacceptable as the process would form part of a script.

Are there any quicker more efficient alternative workaround workflows that can be applied to reduce the processing time yet create the same end product?

Comment: What is the data stored in? Did you do the processing in ArcMap or using arcpy?

Comment: Look at moving all the data to your HD if its on a network and possibly look at using parrallel processing in the environment settings. Additionally you could look at culling your points e.g. would remove duplicate points

Comment: Here are some link that may help - [Link 1](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/53553/18320), [link2](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_8E2337ADAF554C89B2FCADA66DAA400B)