# arcgis halo inside border style?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style

The following was marked as duplicate of the question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53163/how-to-use-directional-shading-on-boundaries-for-cartographic-effect), but I disagree:

### the answers to that question all involve modifying the geometry or making derived geometries, and they deal with shading and transparency rather than fill patterns.  The question below clearly says those options have already been explored and do not do the trick.  I'm looking for a way that does not involve modifying the geometry or making derived geometries - let's face it, we're talking about a style here, not about ways to modify geometry - and is generic to any fill type or transparency level.  If this is still deemed a duplicate question, then the answer must be "no you can't do that as a style".

I'm new to arcgis but have been using qgis for a while.  Question on polygon styles in arcgis:

is there a way to make an 'inside buffer' outline or border style?  I know you can use the buffer tool to make an actual feature that is buffered by a number of geographical distance units, but for this case it would be much better to have a style that has a buffer (or halo) of a certain number of pixels regardless of zoom level, something like this quick hackjob in gimp:

[image]

- solid line for the boundary of the polygon
- inside buffer or halo of a crosshatch pattern >>that does not rotate as a function of polygon outline angle at that point<< (I tried a marker line inside halo (offset by a negative number) and it looks fairly dorky due to rotation along the line)
- the rest is transparent

Can it be done?  Seems like this isn't that unusual of a thing to do.  Boundaries of all sorts are drawn this way on paper maps and they look quite nice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you look at that question, even the OP of that question wanted to know how to apply this as a style. IMHO, giving workarounds to things which are not possible is preferable to have a single line answer saying 'No. You cannot do that' Hence I think that there is no point in opening this question just to give that kind of answer.

Comment: Semantics - I would hope a complete answer would be "no you can't do that with a style; here are some workarounds to do it by editing geometries."  Without anyone on that post having said that you can't do it with a style, that question can still be interpreted as 'unresolved' even though there's an accepted answer.  "No, but..." is a complete answer; neither "no, period" nor "here's how you do something similar" is a complete answer.  Either way you want to word it - the problem is that currently if someone knows of a way to do it as a style, they won't see any open questions to respond to.