# How to create gaussian blur in ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced with Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I am trying to create a gaussian blur for a buffer polygon around a border.

I have Spatial Analyst and ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced, but am not sure if it is possible.

Can anyone suggest a way to do it in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Here are some good methods to try: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53163/how-to-use-directional-shading-on-boundaries-for-cartographic-effect