# Buffer Polygon, BUT Inside and Only for a Distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

There has to be an easy way to do this. Been plugging away for an hour and I don't know if I am brain dead or what.

What I need to do is buffer a polygon on the inside, but only for 500 metres. If you have a look at this image:

[image: Interior Buffer]

You can see exactly what I don't want to do. The selected polygons (cyan) I buffered by -100 metres. What I want to do is actually create a buffer for the area from the polygon boundary to where it buffered it here.

- I know I could do an erase on the original polygon with the above buffered result, but that seems like  an extra step and I want a one step solution.
- I also know I could convert the polygon to a line and then buffer it, but once again extra step extra result.
- Python programming could sure do this, but I really don't want to waste the time going down that road.

I do believe there is a way to do this, with one tool and one result, if not, well Esri should add that in.

**I'm looking to know if there is an Esri ArcGIS Desktop tool to accomplish this?**

Comment: I plan to use the result to display coloured boundaries to differentiate the polygons on a large map. Increasing the border size does not accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there! Using the standard buffer tool, enter your desired distance as a negative value, then **set the `line_side` parameter to `OUTSIDE_ONLY`**. This will generate areas inside of each polygon, giving the nice look of country borders on a political map when combined with a transparency setting:

[image: Input data]

[image: Interior buffer]

Taken from my [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/53170/4669)

Answer (score 3):

Super simple. Change side type to 'Outside Only' and you got it:

[image]

Comment: Once again, an idiot I am.