# Is it possible to create vector style in QGIS that is a border inside border?

Tags: qgis, style

In England, when submitting applications for Countryside Stewardship Scheme woodland grants you are required to mark on a paper map, supplied by the authority, the woodlands that are to be included.

The requirements are very specific, they require a red outside boundary, with a yellow inside, as in the guidance notes that come with the maps. See the image below, where I have added the colour with felt tip pens.

[image]

For large estates with many scattered woodlands this can be very time consuming, and if you make a mistake in your colouring in, you really have to start all over again.

As I already have all the areas as polygons in vector shapefiles I have scanned the maps and georeferenced them into my QGIS project.

Is it possible to replicate this border style of red on the outside and yellow inside that?

I have tried adding another line style for the yellow, and making it wider, but of course this extends both sides of the red border.

[image]

I have found a similar question for ArcGIS [Using directional shading on boundaries for cartographic effect in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53163/using-directional-shading-on-boundaries-for-cartographic-effect-in-arcgis-deskto)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add two symbol layers to your polygons, and change both of them to Outline: Simple Line.

Set the Offset, width, and colours.

Ensure to set the 'Draw line only inside polygon'

It should give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: That did it, thanks. I hadn't noticed you could scroll down in the 'Symbol layer type'. I had just found that I could do something nearly right using the 'Shapeburst fill' and playing around with the draw effects, but this is a much better solution as it gives me a solid yellow line.

Comment: @MartinHügi great!!!

Answer (score 0):

right below in your screenshot,
give a positive offset

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: on the screenshot of @Martin Hügi you may see the "offset" values; but i was mistaken, his screenshot is about the fill, i was thinking about the "simple line" offset