# How can I merge the borders of two countries within the same shapefile?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, borders, crossing

I have a shapefile which visualise the countries of EU as polygons.

The problem I have is that each country is formed by a fill colour and an outline color. The outline color is key because it represent the borders of each country. That works very well when the country has borders with the sea. When the borders of one country meet the borders of another (example Germany-Austria borders) then the color changes because the two borderlines overlap to each other.

Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Without any visual examples of the geometries its hard to say but what you most likely want is to dissolve (qgis processing tool) your borders

Comment: Have you tried setting an inside offset to the boundary, like in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255124/is-it-possible-to-create-vector-style-in-qgis-that-is-a-border-inside-border)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This to me sounds more like an issue with your symbology rather than a need to 'merge' the two countries. If you go into the symbology for the country border layer and offset the border line by a little towards the interior of the polygons, you should be able to present a common border between both countries that maintains the two distinct colors without merging or overlapping of color. The risk here is that you are dealing with sovereign borders, if you bring the offset in too much it will cause error with your visualization. If you truly run a dissolve or merge, you will literally be combining the polygons of two countries together as if there is no border between them.

Comment: Rather than offsetting the border you may add a symbol layer with type "Outline : Simple Line" and check the "draw line only inside polygon" this should prevent offsetting error